# Case statement with AND

Tags: php, mysql, case

i am using age filter in query, i have multiple ages in selection, as below

Under 18
    Under 25
    25-34
    35-44
    45-54
    55-64
    Over 65

i would select the rows from mysql regarding age as below

```
select * from users where isactive=1 
AND (DateOfBirth > (CURDATE() - INTERVAL  $Age YEAR) OR $Age = 0)
```

now i want to add case statement on age if $age variable =25-34 so that i can select related

or any one can tell me how to write and statement inside case like

```
case $age
when $age='25' AND (DateOfBirth > (CURDATE() - INTERVAL  $Age YEAR) OR $Age = 0)
end case
```

Here is Full Query which i is working fine for searching results only age filter is required with case statement for above multiple ages
here is query :

`SELECT  * FROM user
WHERE IsDeleted!=1
AND (IsMale = $Gender OR $Gender = 2)`

/// AT THIS POINT I NEED to add multple case to filter it by ages (after gender filter)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to calculate the year range in script first and then do the query using BETWEEN? That way you would take advantage of any index you may have.

Comment: acutually i have $age var which is coming from user dropdown that has some static values as i mentioned above, i need to use selection regarding that, currently everything is working well, i just need to add case statements regarding age

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine:

```
CASE
  WHEN $age ='25' 
       AND 
       (
         ($Age = 0) 
         OR 
         (DateOfBirth > (CURDATE() - INTERVAL  $Age YEAR))
       )
  Then ...
END
```

Comment: @AshfaqAhmed - What error? And please try to post the whole query you tried

Comment: I think in Case Clause you need to use and `THEN` statement.